# Is kerning letters tighter within a sentence in HTML possible?

Tags: html, inline, kerning

On a webpage I have  24pt "T" next to a 14pt "h" at the beginning of the first paragraph. I would like to slide the "h" under the top bar of the "T". I am aware of the in-line

```
<span style="LETTER-SPACING: 2px;">
```

that adds distance but a '-2' does NOT subtract space. The actual code without the letter-spacing code currently reads as

```
<P><span style='font-size:24.0pt;font-family:"Times Roman","serif"'>T</span>h [.....]</P>
```

Is there a way to do what I want? Right now it looks like this.
[the-jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw98I.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `margin-right: -2px` on the `span` worked for me.

[With negative margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79jI3.png)

[Original, without negative margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvgwC.png)

Comment: Worked! Coded as 
<P><span style="margin-right:-4px"><span style='font-size:24.0pt;font-family:"Jake","serif"'>T</span></span>here is nothing...</P>

Comment: I did end up using the -2 not the -4... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/bkdigital/pen/ZEEpzNE - Demo

```
<P>T<span style="margin-left:-4px">here is nothing</span></P>

p {font-size:24.0pt;font-family:"Times Roman","serif";
  & span {
    font-size: 14pt;
  }}
```

Comment: Please accept as the correct answer if this helps :)

Comment: Didn't work, but the the "right-margin" one below did.